# QGIS is not starting because of deleted file libgeos_c.so.1,How can I fix it

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

QGIS is not starting because of deleted file libgeos_c.so.1,How can I fix it 
It was originally running but some how I have deleted this file for some porpose installation of postgis for postgress but can't start it now.
It shows error as follows on ubuntu 14.04 machine

> /usr/bin/qgis.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall libgeos-c1 using your package manager and don't ever manually remove or change files in your /usr/ directory again.

Comment: tried "  sudo apt-fast install libgeos-c1   "
 it does install but can't help it still asks for "libgeos_c.so.1" file

Comment: Reinstall QGIS as well.

Comment: is packed with QGIS

Comment: Is this the solution for this I want recheck you  know,Am kind of place internet is slow

Comment: I don't know exactly what you did and what package created the libgeos_c.so.1 file. Do you have a libgeos_c.so file now (probably in /usr/lib/, I don't know Ubuntu)? If you compiled QGIS yourself, it might need to be recompiled so it knows where to find the library. If your libgeos_c.so.1 was not from the libgeos-c1 package, then reinstall whatever other package it came from.